# Javascript destructure with computed values, level shifting and new object creation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I get a json response from an api that I want to groom and create a new object from.

```
const things = [{
    "menu": {
      "id": "file",
      "value": "File",
      "popup": {
        "menuitem": [{
            "value": "3",
            "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"
          },
          {
            "value": "5",
            "onclick": "OpenDoc()"
          },
          {
            "value": "8",
            "onclick": "CloseDoc()"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "menu": {
      "id": "image",
      "value": "Image",
      "popup": {
        "menuitem": [{
            "value": "New",
            "onclick": "CreateNewImage()"
          },
          {
            "value": "Open",
            "onclick": "OpenImage()"
          },
          {
            "value": "Close",
            "onclick": "CloseImage()"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
];
```

I know the old way of doing this like so:

```
const chs = [];
things.forEach((e) => {
    const i = {};
    i.Id = e.menu.id;
    i.Value = e.menu.value;
    i.PopupValue = e.menu.popup.menuitem[0].value;
    i.SomethingComputed = e.menu.popup.menuitem[0].value - e.menu.popup.menuitem[1];
    i.ShiftedUp = e.menu.popup.menuitem;
    chs.push(ch);
  });
```

now I want to do this using ES6 and destructuring. but I don't think I have taken it as far as I can go because I: 1)still have the loop; 2)have to create this new object; and 3) need these separate computed lines.
Can I get this more compact?

```
const chs = [];
things.forEach((e) => {
    const {
        Id: {id},
        Value: {value},
        PopupValue : {menu: {popup} },
    } = e;

    // computed 
    const someComputedValue = Value - PopupValue;

    // new object
    const ch = {
        Id,
        Value,
        SomeComputedValue
    }

    chs.push(ch);
});
```

Comment: You can improve the readibility by using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead of `Array#forEach`. Destructuring might help you to make it more compact, but not to make it more readable in this case.

Comment: The *old way* is clean, readable and probably faster than using destructuring.

Comment: @adiga No, there's nothing inherently slow about destructuring.

Comment: Your destructuring is slightly off. The assigned variable goes inside, the property name goes onto the left like in a normal object literal.

Comment: @Bergi I assumed creating variables and assigning nested object values and then creating objects might be *slightly* slower than directly creating an object literal

Comment: @adiga Temporary variables generally don't affect speed, the interpreter has to store intermediate results somewhere anyway - and when compiled, the same data flow graph (with or without additional variables) usually leads to the same register assignment.

Comment: @adiga Thinking about it, the first snippet is probably even slower than the destructuring into temporary variables, since the (costly) property accesses have to repeated multiple times. The optimiser would have to go at great lengths to deduce that it can safely collapse them into a single one per property, proofing that they don't have side effects (e.g. are getter properties on some of the objects).

Comment: @Bergi thanks for all those details. Now I'm glad I wrote *probably faster* tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map()` instead of `forEach()`, so you don't need the `chs.push()` step at the end.

You can put the destructuring directly in the argument list, so you don't need the assignment step. Whether this is more readable is debatable.

If the calculation for `SomeComputedValue` isn't too complex, you can put it directly in the returned object. Then you can get rid of that assignment, and you can use the shorthand form of arrow function that just returns a value.

```js
const things = [{
    "menu": {
      "id": "file",
      "value": "File",
      "popup": {
        "menuitem": [{
            "value": "3",
            "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"
          },
          {
            "value": "5",
            "onclick": "OpenDoc()"
          },
          {
            "value": "8",
            "onclick": "CloseDoc()"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {},
  {
    "menu": {
      "id": "image",
      "value": "Image",
      "popup": {
        "menuitem": [{
            "value": "New",
            "onclick": "CreateNewImage()"
          },
          {
            "value": "Open",
            "onclick": "OpenImage()"
          },
          {
            "value": "Close",
            "onclick": "CloseImage()"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
];

const chs = things.map(({
menu: {
    id: Id,
    value: Value,
    popup : PopupValue,
} = {id: "defaultID", value: "defaultValue", popup: "defaultPopup"}}) => ({
        Id,
        Value,
        SomeComputedValue: Value - PopupValue
    })
);

console.log(chs);
```

Comment: You copied the wrong destructuring from the OP. Can you fix that, please?

Comment: I think I copied it correctly from the second code snippet.

Comment: Yes, you copied it, but it doesn't work. See the other answers for the correct version (that is equivalent to what the OP does in his first snippet)

Comment: I assumed his version worked, and he's just looking for a more elegant way to write it (although that now suggests that [codereview.se] might be better).

Comment: I liked this one the best. thank you very much for the assistance. and I apologize about the code in my OP, it was butchered to obfuscate some things and i didn't do the best job of that.

Comment: just a quick follow-up - what if the 'menu' key was not present on some of the objects? how could i handle that gracefully by inserting a default?

Comment: `PopupValue: {menu: {popup} = {popup: defaultValue}}`

Comment: Anything that's optional can be followed by a default value like that.

Comment: it's blowing up in the map call saying that it can't read property 'menu' of undefined

Comment: I had everything in the destructuring pattern backwards, and it also didn't match the objects in `things`. I've updated the answer to show the correct way to write it, including the default menu value. I don't understand what you expect `Value - PopupValue` to mean, since `Value` is a string and `PopupValue` is an object, so you can't subtract them.

Answer (score 1):

The non-destructuring way is actually more like this:

```
const chs = things.map(e => ({
  Id: e.menu.id,
  Value: e.menu.value,
  PopupValue: e.menu.popup.menuitem[0].value,
  SomethingComputed: e.menu.popup.menuitem[0].value - e.menu.popup.menuitem[1],
  ShiftedUp: e.menu.popup.menuitem,
}));
```

And destructuring, or just the general concept of splitting stuff into more variables, doesn’t have to be all or nothing:

```
const chs = things.map(({menu}) => {
  const {menuitem} = menu.popup;

  return {
    Id: menu.id,
    Value: menu.value,
    PopupValue: menuitem[0].value,
    SomethingComputed: menuitem[0].value - menuitem[1],
    ShiftedUp: menuitem,
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but it is possible to do this using destructuring. You could create a arrow function like this which destructures each object in the array and returns a new object. Then use that as callback to [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const things=[{menu:{id:"file",value:"File",popup:{menuitem:[{value:"3",onclick:"CreateNewDoc()"},{value:"5",onclick:"OpenDoc()"},{value:"8",onclick:"CloseDoc()"}]}}},{menu:{id:"image",value:"Image",popup:{menuitem:[{value:"New",onclick:"CreateNewImage()"},{value:"Open",onclick:"OpenImage()"},{value:"Close",onclick:"CloseImage()"}]}}}];

const callback = ({
  menu: {
    id: Id,
    value: Value,
    popup: {
      menuitem
    }
  }
}) => ({
  Id,
  Value,
  ShiftedUp: menuitem,
  PopupValue: menuitem[0].value,
  SomethingComputed: menuitem[0].value - menuitem[1].value
})

console.log(things.map(callback))
```

You could even destrcuture the `menuitem` array indexes to get the first 2 `value`s to separate variables like this:

```
const callback = ({
  menu: {
    id: Id,
    value: Value,
    popup: {
      menuitem
    },
    popup: {
      menuitem: [
        { value: Value0 },
        { value: Value1 }
      ]
    }
  }
}) => ({
  Id,
  Value,
  ShiftedUp: menuitem,
  PopupValue: Value0,
  SomethingComputed: Value0 - Value1
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid loop because `things` is an array so you have to iterate it. However you can avoid new object creation and pushing in `chs` array using the `map` function because it essentially creates a new element for each element of the orignial array and returns the array with newly created elements or objects in you case. So basically both looping and new object creation will be handled by the `map` function in this case.

Also, you can move the destructuring to the callback parameter of the map function and computation can be performed while returning the object:

```
const chs=things.map(({menu:{id,value,popup}}) => ({
        Id: id,
        Value: value,
        PopupValue : popup,
        SomeComputedValue: value+id

    }) 
);
```

I have tested the above destructuring, it works for your `things` array as you provided it.